# How to create OLAP cube using Oracle DW

Tags: ssas, olap, cube, olap-cube, oracle-olap

Whether it's possible to create cube using SSAS by establishing connection with Oracle DW?
Whish is the best tool to use SSAS/Oracle OLAP?
What are the requirements?
How to install the tool?

PS: I have very limited knowledge on data cubes

Comment: That's a very broad question

Comment: My objective is to build a data cube using relational table from Oracle DB. Whether I can do the job using SSAS? Since SSAS is a product of Microsoft. Does it establish connection with Oracle?

Comment: Yes this is a broad question. I need more information from scratch. I don't have prior experience with OLAP/Cube

Comment: SSAS can connect to Oracle and you can use that to build the cube. That's the broad answer to your question ;) you can start doing it and when you reach a specific problem ask

Comment: Thanks @VeselinDavidov. Let me connect SSAS with Oracle DW and have build it using SSAS. where the cube would be stored? Whether I have to purchase SQL Server license in order to store the cube in it's server?

Comment: I have installed the following softwares:

Comment: 1. SQL Server 2. Visual Studio 3. SSDT 4. BIDS 5. SSMS

Comment: Whether I have to install/purchase any other software to set-up?

Answer (score 0):

SSAS uses a relational database as its data source. According to Microsoft, that relational database can be an Oracle database by using the Oracle OLE DB Provider.

You would need a SQL Server license to build SSAS cubes.

I have built cubes using Oracle OLAP (using Oracle relational database) and SSAS (using SQL Server) but have not personally tried using Oracle as the data source to SSAS. These days, you are better off with SSAS.